# PictureBox doesn't show up in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am trying to create a custom error dialog, that has a red x on the left hand side. Below is my code;

```
using JohnsonControls.FieldBusFDD.Properties;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JohnsonControls.FieldBusFDD
{
    public class ErrorDialog : Dialog
    {
        public static bool ShowDialog(string text, string title)
        {
            Form prompt = new Form();
            prompt.Width = 435;
            prompt.Height = 122;
            prompt.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            prompt.Text = title;
            prompt.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            PictureBox image = new PictureBox();
            image.Image = Resources.red_x;
            image.Location = new Point(10, 10);
            image.Size = new Size(50, 50);

            Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 60, Top = 10, Width = 350, Text = text };

            Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 300, Width = 100, Top = 52 };
            confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
            confirmation.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

            prompt.Controls.Add(image);
            prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
            prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

            return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```

The file is stored in the project resources, and compiles just fine but the image is not displayed.

Comment: are you sure the code ain't working for you? I just had look at the code and managed to run code, and I was able to get the dialog box with the specified image (a jpg file). I didn't alter your code at all. Are you sure `red_x` is proper image and you verify this by trying to view using an image viewer.

Comment: @fujiFX Yes, are .png's not supported?

Comment: I guess the pixel size of the image is too big? Try `image.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;`.

Comment: @ripple, That worked. Create an answer, and I'll pick it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the pixel size of the image is too big, the `PictureBox` only shows the upper-left corner of the image by default.

Try this:

```
image.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx):

> By default, in Normal mode, the Image is positioned in the upper-left corner of the PictureBox, and any part of the image that is too big for the PictureBox is clipped. Using the StretchImage value causes the image to stretch or shrink to fit the PictureBox. Using the Zoom value causes the image to be stretched or shrunk to fit the PictureBox; however, the aspect ratio in the original is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Try to strecth image on your picture box by:

```
 image.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

[Using the StretchImage value causes the image to stretch or shrink to fit the PictureBox.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx)